# How can I use python to catch the signal of Windows taskill /f command

Tags: python, signals

my English is not good,my question please see the title.Could I use python to catch the signal of command taskkill /f /pid?

Answer (score 0):

Invoking "taskkill /f <pid>" for a process is equivalent to calling TerminateProcess(pid). It is a low level termination of the process and it not possible for a program to catch the signal, see e.g. here for a rationale: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/22/191123.aspx.